# Communication link failure..Connection reset

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, c3p0

My application occasionally sees this exception while talking to MySQL database using Hibernate. I tried tuning in C3p0 properties but it does not seem to work.

Here are C3p0 related settings:

```
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.acquire_increment">2</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period">60</property><!-- in seconds -->
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size">2</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size">10</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout">180</property>
<property name="hibernate.c3p0.preferredTestQuery">select 1</property>
```

Connection url looks like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://<DB endpoint>?autoReconnect=true&useUniCode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=true&requireSSL=true&verifyServerCertificate=false
```

Stacktrace is:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
Last packet sent to the server was 1549998 ms ago.

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: 
Connection reset
```

Do I need to tweak MySQL system variables? Any pointers how can we avoid this exception?

Thanks
Jitendra

Comment: When I checked my logs, it seems that all exceptions came from one particular connection which was stale. These exceptions were thrown across the span of half an hour. I thought 'idle_test_period' would check validity of connections every 60 secs.

Comment: can you please add testOnBorrow=”true” into your config try this and lets know about the issues..

Comment: Log also shows this message : [managed:2 unused:2 excluded:1] I am wondering what does 'excluded:1' mean here?

Comment: I would assume this is status of connections available in the pool

Comment: 'excluded' means that c3p0 noticed an Exception that occurred while a client was using a Connection, and has marked that Connection to be destroyed rather than reused when it is checked back into the pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period -- or c3p0.idleConnectionTestPeriod will test every 60 secs only if a Connection is idle for 60 secs. if your app is very active, it won't be idle for so long. c3p0 tries to notice when Exceptions received by the application mean the Connection should be invalidated, but that depends on the SQLState of the Exception, which is inconsistent across databases/JDBC drivers and not entirely reliable. It's rare for a dead Connection to survive multiple rounds of checkin/checkout, but under your settings it could happen.

the simplest solution is to add c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckin to your config. that ensures, regardless of whether Connections are busy or idle, that Connections will be tested before being allowed into the pool, without incurring the synchronous overhead of testing on checkout.

please do see http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

also please verify that the config params you are setting are getting through to the underlying Connection pool. c3p0 dumps its config to your logs at INFO level on pool init: check your logs to verify that your settings are what you think they are. (alternatively you can inspect your pools while your application is running via jmx.)

good luck!

Comment: Thanks Steve. I will try both suggestions, confirming c3p0 settings being picked up and testConnectionOnCheckin.

Answer (score 3):

It sounds like you have some connections in your pool and use only part of them. Some of them just wait to be used, and get stale (connection gets reset for some reason - ex. some timeout on DB side). Then when in some moment you try to use them, you get the exception.

There are usually a few options to fix this, for example you can test connections before retrieving it from pool (hibernate.c3p0.testConnectionOnCheckout)

You can additionally periodically check status of connections in pool and/or check connections on checkIn. See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

If it doesn't help - the whole stacktrace might be useful.

Comment: This is quite false. c3p0 permits testing of Connections on checkout, checkins, and when idle. See http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/#configuring_connection_testing

Comment: You are right Steve.I checked some old documentation of release which didn't have this feature. Thanks for tip. I the updated post.